# Framework 4.6.1 not showing in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, .net-4.6.1, .xproj

I have a windows 10 pro PC, which had Visual Studio 2017. For a project requirement, I uninstalled that and installed VS2015 update 3.

(which was supposed to already have .NET Framework 4.6.1), but it did not!!!.

I manually downloaded and installed [.NET Framework 4.6.1 developer pack](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/net461-developer-pack).
It does show up in control panel programs as 'Targeting Pack (ENU)', but not in VS. why?

[image]

The reason I wanted 4.6.1 was, the solution i have to work on, has some .xproj extension projects. I think VS is not able to convert/build them to .csproj and hence the build errors.

[image]

I'm only hoping that getting 4.6.1 to show up in VS, might fix the real issue.

Any thoughts?

Comment: repair VS2015 and reinstall the .net 4.6.1 target pack

Comment: As @magicandre1981 suggested, repair VS first and then reinstall 4.6.1.  In certain scenarios, you may have to uninstall and reinstall 4.6.1 so that way it is properly acquired by VS from the GAC.  In super rare instances, you may have not have the correct permissions to see the FX.  Also, provide us the Error List pictured, that may provide more insight into the actual problem than anything else.